# how to obtain $b*a$ if we know $a*b$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a high school student and we firstly learn something about abstract algebra this week.I want to learn the idea behing the difference between $a*b$ and $b*a$

It is given that $a*b=a^3 -b^2+4a+3b$ where $*$ is an algebraic operation. It is asked to find $b*a$.

I thought that I should put "a" in place of $b$ in $a*b$, and put "b" in place of $a$ in $a*b$. So, $b*a=b^3-a^2+4b+3a$. Am I right ? What is the idea ?

**Edition:** I think people thought my question as ambiguous.  So, I am try to find what $b*a$ if $a*b=a^3 -b^2+4a+3b$ holds for all a and b values

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: That depends on whether $a*b=a^3-b^2+4a+3b$ was given as a formula for *all* $a,b$ or if it was given as relationship for that *specific* $a$ and that *specific* $b$.  I suspect it was given as a specific.  In which case, no, you can not replace the variables because they are *not* variables.  They are specific constants.

Comment: I think you are wrong.

Comment: I also think you're right about the original problem, but you have not fully represented the original context of the question, which would have indicated whether $a*b$ was previously defined using some other formula or whether this formula is the definition of $a*b$. My guess is there is no other definition, that $a*b=a^3 -b^2+4a+3b$ is the definition of $a*b$, and therefore the only thing the symbols $a$ and $b$ tell us is where to copy the symbol on the left of the $*$ into the formula and where to copy the symbol on the right of the $*$, which is what you did.

Comment: If you want an unambiguous answer to the question, try making the question less ambiguous by editing it to tell us more about how it was presented to you.

Comment: *I want to learn the idea behing the difference between $a*b$ and $b*a$* - then start with a different example, namely take the matrix product of $A$ and $B$ and try to see yourself that in general $AB\neq BA$.

Comment: Take the group $G=GL_n(\Bbb R)$ of invertible matrices to understand the group composition $A\circ B:=AB$, which is matrix multiplication. This is exactly what you asked in your **Edition**. Do not randomly write down $a^3-b^2+4a+3b$, but rather take a natural non-abelian operation like matrix multiplication.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think the example is fine, actually, as an exploration of what we mean by an operation. Whether we can build a group using this particular operation seems to me to be beside the point.

Comment: @DavidK No, I don't think so. The OP explicitly asks: *My teacher talked about this operation in groups. So, I am try to find what* ∗ *in group theory etc. Because i try to decide whether a group is commuttive or not.* A very general example of a non-commutative group is the general linear group. Matrices are very concrete and helpful here, and certainly not beside the point.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am not interested in groups, I just want to see what is $b*a$ if I know $a*b$

Comment: The ambiguity in the question is that we do not know exactly what you mean when you write, "It is given that $a*b=a^3 -b^2+4a+3b$ where $*$ is an algebraic operation." If you meant this statement to be the *definition* of $*$ then I would expect something like, "Let $*$ be an algebraic operation such that $a*b=a^3-b^2+4a+3b$ for all integers $a$ and $b$." The way you wrote it, it is not clear that this statement (rather than some other statement not shown in the question) is the definition of $*$.

Comment: @DavidK please look at my last comment

Comment: You talked about $a*b$ in a group yourself - not me!

Comment: @DietrichBurde not interested in matrices, ı just want to see for my specific question, dont make question unrelated

Comment: @pauli The change you made was an unfortunate one, because we really wanted to know what the purpose of the equation $a*b=a^3 -b^2+4a+3b$ was, and instead you wrote a lot of stuff about groups, which (as you say) is not really what you wanted to ask about.

Comment: You said: *we firstly learn something about abstract algebra this week*. The most important first basic thing in abstract algebra is the notion of a group with composition $a\circ b$, as your teacher said.

Comment: @DavidK yes , it holds for all a and b values for $a*b$ and I want to see $b*a$ using $a*b$

Comment: So you meant that $a*b=a^3 -b^2+4a+3b$ is the way the operation $*$ is defined. Then you wrote $b*a$ correctly.

Comment: This time you edited the question in a way that makes it clear.

Comment: I still think that your question is unclearly stated.  As a *guess*, I *think* that the question you are trying to ask is something like this:  "Let $A$ be a set, and define a binary operation $\ast$ on the set $A$ by $a\ast b := a^3 - b^2  + 4a + 3b$.  What is $b \ast a$?"  Is this what you are after?

Comment: @XanderHenderson it seems that it is what is wanted

Comment: @XanderHenderson what do you think about the answer ? there are two distinct answers below

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish I am not sure what you are asking from me.  I think that the question is unclear, and that the asker should have addressed the lack of clarity.  As the asker seems to have left the site (the account no longer exists) and the lack of clarity has not been addressed, I would recommend closure and deletion (since it is not clear that *either* of the answers addresses the question that the asker had.

Answer (score 2):

I see from the third version of the question that you mean to define the binary algebraic operation $*$ as follows:

> $a*b=a^3 -b^2+4a+3b$ holds for all $a$ and $b$ values [in some set of values that you are thinking of].

The symbols $a$ and $b$ in this definition are merely placeholder symbols to tell us what to do with the values that we find on the left and right sides of the symbol $*$. We take the value on the left of $*$ and put it wherever we see $a$ in the definition. We take the value on the right of $*$ and put it wherever we see $b$ in the definition.

If we want to know what to do with $b*a$, we have $b$ on the left side of $*$, so we put it wherever we see $a$ in the original definition, and we have $a$ on the right side of $*$, so we put it wherever we see $b$ in the original definition.
When we have done all of this, the result is

$$ b*a=b^3 -a^2+4b+3a, $$

exactly as you concluded.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what this question is asking is whether, given the value of $a*b$ and the expression for it, can you find the value of $b*a$ without needing the values of $a$ and $b$. (i.e. if $a*b$ is some sort of polynomial or rational function of $b*a$.)

I am biased on this due to my experience with olympiad problems of this sort which usually mean things similar to this.

In any case, for this interpretation that I am saying, I think the answer is negative. The reason is that, after some algebra (if I did not screw up), you can prove that
\begin{equation}
 a*b -b*a = \frac{a^4-1}{a-1} - \frac{b^4-1}{b-1},
\end{equation}
and so we see that the difference indeed depends on the particular values of $a$ and $b$.

To put a concrete example, imagine we are told $a*b = 6$. Turns out that there are several options to what $b*a$ could be. For example, $a = 2, b = 0$ and $a = 2, b = 3$ both produce $a*b = 6$. However
\begin{equation}
 0*2 = 2, \; 3*2 = 41,
\end{equation}
showing that you cannot determined the flipped product from the other one. You really need the values of $a$ and $b$ or more information on the specifics.

However, this difference can help to determine extra stuff. For example, you could prove
\begin{equation}
 a*b + b*c + c*a = b*a + c*b + a*c,
\end{equation}
because the right hands cancel, which might or might not tell you something of what you ant to study but that a priori might not be obvious from the direct expression.